# Sort files then pass them to awk for search

Tags: bash, awk

I want to search through a list of files and get a list of the results. For that I have:

```
awk 'tolower($0) ~ /hauerwas/' RS= ORS="\\n\\n**********************\\n\\n" *
```

Works good except the results are in the wrong order. I want the results from the newer *FILES* on top. Not sort the results, but sort the files then search them.

So I tried to create a variable from an 'ls' command sorted the way I want, then run the awk on each file in the variable. This is what I have:

```
theFile=`ls -r`; for file in "$theFile"; do awk 'tolower($0) ~ /hauerwas/' "$file"; done
```

Doesn't work. Just spits on a listing of the files.

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `for file in "$theFile"`

The quotes shut off wordsplitting, if you know there's no white space in your file names just lose them; otherwise  you'll do better with something like

```
find -type f -exec ls -t {} + \
| xargs -d\\n awk 'tolower($0)~/hauerwas/' RS= ORS=$'\n\n**********************\n\n'
```

Comment: I think I'm close. It looks like the macOS xargs command does not support the delimiter parameter, so I remove that. I currently have `find . -type f -exec ls -r {} + \ | xargs awk /hauerwas/` - The error is `find:  : unknown primary or operator`

Comment: The backslash is there to escape the linebreak in the answer, if you put it all on one line it's in front of a space, and it'll add a space-character arg that find won't like.

Comment: Look up how to get xargs to read lines if you're worried about white space in the filenames, looks like on the mac you feed it a `-J` with a placeholder, so `xargs -J %` then your awk with a `%` on the end where the filenames should go.  Apple carries some now-extremely old versions of the GNU userland and have made their own quirky modifications to them, so you get to deal with that (perhaps by using `brew` to install a current GNU)

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!! So amazing. You're a wizard. Thanks so much. 

Answer (score 2):

You could do (assuming GNU tools, and assuming none of your filenames contain newlines)

```sh
mapfile -t sortedByMtimeDesc < <(stat -c '%Y %n' * | sort -nr | cut -d " " -f 2-)
awk ... "${sortedByMtimeDesc[@]}"
```

Comment: I should have mentioned - I'm on macOS 10.14.6 (Mojave) - Do I have the needed tools for this?

Comment: Yes, just that stat takes slightly different options. Read the man page

Comment: I can't seem to get the 'mapfile' command to work on macOS. I updated to Bash 5 thinking that would include it, but it still says `-bash: mapfile: command not found` - Hmm.